# I am looking for a software, program like terminal in fedora

Tags: windows-8

I am looking for a software, program like terminal in fedora to compile and run programs for Windows 64-bit.

I want to be able to compile and run programs just like I am working in Fedora. Please anyone suggest me.

Comment: I'd also add that its unclear whether you mean a compiler, makefile compatibility, or a terminal. You do not really use a terminal to compile - you typically use a compiler, sometimes with the assistance of some flavour of make file to compile programs. Even if this wasn't a software rec, its unclear *what* your actual needs are.

Comment: i just want anything that makes me like i m working on linux system...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to use a text based interface in Windows, you can do so through Command Prompt (accessible through  "Run->Cmd" or "Command Promt" Icon, not sure if it has a place for it by default in Win8's modern UI). If you want to compile C or anyother language programs, all you need to do is install the necessary tools and invoke the appropriate commands from command prompt. For instance, refer the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384838.aspx) that explains how to compile C programs from command prompt when Visual Studio is installed.

If you indeed want access to Terminal similar to the one available in Linux, you can make use of [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com). This way you can install the same packages you have in Linux and use them in windows). Be aware that not all packages will be compatible!

Another option is, if the linux and windows instances are available in two separate machines connected over a network, you can use any SSH client utility on Windows to gain access to the other machine.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/):

> a large collection of GNU and Open Source tools which provide functionality similar to a Linux distribution on Windows.